Using Spyder IDE in WSL2, I'm Told Working Directory Does not Exist (It Does Exist)
I'm running a program in Spyder which is saved in \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\<user>\<directory. I'm able to run the program without issue - the correct output is printed to the console and I can see the variables generated during the execution of the program. However, the following is printed to the console after execution has completed:
runfile('//wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/<user>/directory/program.py', wdir='//wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/<user>/directory')
Working directory //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/<user>/directory doesn't exist.

So why is Spyder telling me the directory doesn't exist?

Do does //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home//directory exist?

I'm guessing you meant to say, "So, does ... exist?" And yes, it does.

So it’s accessible through File Explorer. What about WSL? What version of Windows? What version of the WSL kernel do you have installed?

The directory is also accessible through WSL. I'm running Windows 11 and I have the Linux kernel I have installed is version 5.15.146.1

You have verified the working directory is correct? I assume the error is being displayed in the same location as this error was.

I figured it out!

I was able to make the message disappear by going to Tools -> Preferences -> Run -> Working directory settings and selecting "The current working directory" instead of "The directory of the file being executed".
